# Logstash - Error during the load of keystore loading

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

I'm trying to run logstash with elasticsearch and i got an error when i launch logstash, this error happen after the start of logtash, the creation of all the full, partial and after all the SQL operation. It seem's to ba a connection error but i'm not sure.

[Error]
Error during the load of keystore loading

It's weird that it's happening at the very end of the process

Thank you for your help.

Comment: We need configuration file and the rest of the logs around the error message. Thanks!

Comment: thank you for your reply, i will send you the logs tomorrow